# Get flash data in template

Tags: symfony, twig, session-variables, symfony-2.3

im try get flashData in a Twig template. In the controller i set:

```
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
$session->getFlashBag()->add('ok_menu', true);
$session->getFlashBag()->add('msg_menu', 'Las selecciones del menu fueron guardadas correctamente.');
```

And in the profiler, are displayed:

[image]

In the template i write this:

```
{% if app.session.get('ok_menu') is defined %}
    {% if app.session.get('ok_menu') %}
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <strong>&Eacute;xito:</strong> {{ app.session.get('msg_menu') }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

But, in the page not reder the flash messages.
Any ideas ?.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to access the values from the `flashbag` property.

```
{% if app.session.flashbag.has('ok_menu') %}
    {% if app.session.flashbag.get('ok_menu') %}
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <strong>&Eacute;xito:</strong> {{ app.session.flashbag.get('msg_menu') }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: thanks ! works, but with 'msg_menu' use: `app.session.flashbag.get('msg_menu')[0]`

Comment: @ramiromd I would recommend the use of a `for` loop in case there would be several messages in the flash bag and you would therefore not need to access `app.session.flashbag.get('msg_menu')[0]`